# Problemas com MySQL Server para OS X

Tags: mysql, osx, banco-de-dados

Olá,

Alguém, aqui, já conseguiu instalar o `MySQL` Server para Mac?
Instalei, mas não consigo iniciá-lo! Clico no botão do painel dele, pede a senha, digito e nada.
Tento pelo `Terminal`, fica processando e depois diz:

> ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/mysql/data/MacBook-Pro.local.pid).

Answer (score 1):

Pode ser concorrência. Neste caso, sugiro você matar todos os processos do mysqld e iniciar novamente.

Dê uma olhada neste artigo que indica o procedimento:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34662343/2788478

Pode ser permissão de acesso. Dê uma olhada nesta solução.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9704993/2788478

Achei interessante este artigo também:

http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/mysql-error-server-quit-without-updating-pid-file/

Comment: Matando todas as execuções de mysql, ai consegui iniciar.

Comment: obrigado por partilhar o sucesso.

Comment: Eu já uso o MAMP pra rodar minha aplicações. Tem algum problema rodar o mysql server junto?

Comment: @GustavoSevero, não. nenhum. O problema dele foi outro. Haviam mais processos do mysqld fazendo lock no pid. Ele matou todos e reiniciou o server.

Comment: Outro problema que aparece, é no workbench, quando ele tenta iniciar o server ele procura pelo arquivo nv.cnf ou algo assim, mas não existe, o que eu achei nas pastas foi o my-default.cnf